# using specific fonts in iphone 4 but not before version 3.2

Tags: iphone, fonts

I am using the external fonts capability for my application. 
As external fonts are not supported in 3.1 version I would like to define the font name in relation with the IOS that is executing the program.  I have defined MY_FONT_NAME variable in a Constants.h file like this:

```
  //#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_3_2
  #ifdef __IPHONE_3_2
    #define MY_FONT_NAME @"ExternalFontName"    
  #else
    #define MY_FONT_NAME @"AppleGothic"
  #endif
```

I have tried both, the first commented line and the second, without success but it always get the value of "externalFontName", even executing on a 3.1 device... and so, when I set the font in a label I get the error

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: font != nil'

Anyone know what is the problem?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better approach would be to use UIFont's `+fontWithName:size:` to check the availability of the font, and / or examining the returned arrays from `+familyNames` and
`+fontNamesForFamilyName:`.

For example, I believe there are some fonts that are only present on the iPad running 3.2, even versus an iPhone running 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I know, the macros are executed on compilation time, that is the problem..  so stupid! sorry :)

So I think I should use something like:

```
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] >= @"3.2") {
    return @"myExternalFontName";
} else {
    return @"AppleGothic";
}
```

Or does anyone has a better solution?  Thanks

Comment: Good idea. :) (SO has got a STUPID character limit..)

Answer (score 1):

Eva Madrazo is close. What you actually need is:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]doubleValue] >= 3.2) {
```

because a string compare doesn't cut it.